# Relationship between *-homomorphism and isometries

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

One of the possible way to define a sum of two extension is:

> Let $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{A}$ be two separable C*-algebras with $\mathcal{B}$ stable and $\phi,\psi: \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{M(B)/B}$ be two extensions of $\mathcal{B}$ by $\mathcal{A}$. Then the sum of extension is defined in the following way:
> $$(\phi \oplus \psi)(a)=\pi(S)\phi(a)\pi(S^*)+\pi(T)\psi(a)\pi(T^*)$$
> where $S,T \in \mathcal{M(B)}$ are isometries such that $SS^*+TT^*=1_{\mathcal{M(B)}}$.

The condition $SS^*+TT^*=1_{\mathcal{M(B)}}$ makes sure that the defined sum is still a *-homomorphism. I wonder if there is some deeper connection between isometries and *-homomorphisms in general. I guess what I am asking myself here is how would I guess that to end up with a *-homomorphism I need isometries here. It feels like there is more behind this then I see right now. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think it is useful to make the analogy with Hilbert spaces $H,K$. You have isometries $S: H\to H\oplus K$ and $T: K\to H \oplus K$ which satisfy $SS^* + TT^* = 1$. Given operators $u \in B(H)$ and $v\in B(K)$, you can form $u\oplus v\in B(H\oplus K)$ which satisfies $u \oplus v= SuS^* + TvT^*$. A similar thing is going on here, and the point is basically that you are somehow making a direct sum of $*$-homomorphisms. Because there is only something on the diagonal, and not on the two other remaining corners, you get something that is compatible with the $*$-algebra operations.